# how to get password while replicating data in cloudant bluemix?

Tags: cloudant, ibm-cloud

I am trying to replicate database in cloudant and I added a database name in the "My Databses" entry tab. On clicking replicate it's asking for a password
I used my bluemix password but it's not working.

can anyone help to get this password ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

while replicating the database, cloudant doesn't take bluemix password. 
You can simply follow these steps here: 
1) go to your dashboard and clock on your app.
2) Cloudant NoSQL DB should be listed as a service in your app. 
3) click on show credentials 
4) it will give you a list of different entries, and your username and password will be also listed there. your password will be listed in following form:
"password": "3b0c7b5305daa1616130e4d3e29a24b15a879215ccd56f568396110d55241041",

copy all the characters under inverted commas, this will be your password.

Comment: I tried every password reset imaginable. This worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

This issue is already addressed via below developer work article:

https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/23347/accessing-vcap-services-environment-variable-via-bluemix-dashboard.html

In short,you need to use VCAP_SERVICES to access all the details of db(via dash board) & include it your application code.

Below is the sample usgae of VCAP_SERVICES in node.js+mongodb to get all the details(including passwd) generated by bluemix dashboard:

```
console.log('VCAP SERVICES: ' + JSON.stringify(process.env.VCAP_SERVICES, null, 4));

var mongoUrl;

if(process.env.VCAP_SERVICES) {

var vcapServices = JSON.parse(process.env.VCAP_SERVICES);

for (var svcName in vcapServices) {

if (svcName.match(/^mongo.*/)) {

  mongoUrl = vcapServices[svcName][0].credentials.uri;

  mongoUrl = mongoUrl || vcapServices[svcName][0].credentials.url;

  break;

}

}
```

Hope it will helps.